# Does pain scale with mammal mass?

Tags: neuroscience, skin, pain, allometry

Some biological features scale with the animal mass (see [previous Q&A](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8357/what-are-some-examples-of-scaling-laws-in-biology)).

Assuming the same concentration of nociceptors on the skin surface, I'm wondering how painful a 1 cm wound will be perceived in mouse, human or elephant. Despite the same firing number of nociceptors, will the mouse feel more pain as a bigger percentage of the body has been injured? Is it known whether pain sensing follows [allometric rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allometry)?

Comment: As you cannot really ask a mouse to rank her sense of pain on a scale of 1 to 10, it will not be possible to find a definitive answer for your question.

Comment: @skymninge there are at least 40 [animal models of neuropathic] (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20030738), but I'm not inside the field and cannot judge if some of them can be used for allometric studies.

Comment: The question if the mouse will FEEL bigger pain is still debatable. As pain is a feeling, not even by questioning different humans you could measure how much pain is felt. You can measure reactions, but pain is a subjective feeling. If I have an especially bad day, cutting my finger might (feel to) hurt more, than on a day I feel very euphoric.